# (djstripe.C001) Could not find a Stripe API key. HINT: Add STRIPE_TEST_SECRET_KEY and STRIPE_LIVE_SECRET_KEY to your settings

Tags: django, stripe-payments

Stripe keys are not being detected correctly and I don't know where the error is in DJStripe.

Here is how my Stripe is configured:

```
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get("STRIPE_SECRET_KEY", "sk_live_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY = os.environ.get("STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
STRIPE_TEST_SECRET_KEY = "sk_live_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
STRIPE_TEST_PUBLIC_KEY = "pk_live_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

This is the error:

```
CRITICALS:
?: (djstripe.C001) Could not find a Stripe API key.
        HINT: Add STRIPE_TEST_SECRET_KEY and STRIPE_LIVE_SECRET_KEY to your settings.
?: (djstripe.C006) DJSTRIPE_WEBHOOK_VALIDATION='verify_signature' but DJSTRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET is not set
        HINT: Set DJSTRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET or set DJSTRIPE_WEBHOOK_VALIDATION='retrieve_event'
```

Comment: Check your names exactly mention in settings.py

Comment: sorry i didn't completely understand the answer

Comment: Is it just a typo that `STRIPE_TEST_SECRET_KEY = "sk_live_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` doesn't have a closing quotation? Also, you've configured this in settings.py right?

Comment: yep, in  base.py, that it is not a typo because i've tried with the close quotation already.